# Web Design, Custom Image changed with drop down selection box?

Tags: website-design

I am curious to know how those "customize -random product-" objects are built. I assume some sort of flash is involved. There are many websites that allow you to customize shoes, shirts etc, and when you choose an option, it changes the product as you continue through the creation process. What is that being built with?

More specifically (because it may be a different way), Id like to know what would be the most appropriate way to build something like this:

Picture (or object) is on right side of page, in its most natural state. - Lets say its a HOCKEY STICK. There are 3 drop down selection boxes in middle of screen. The first is color, i click that and choose Red (+$2.00) or what have you, then the HOCKEY STICK to the right changes to a red hockey stick. Then the second drop down allows me to change the curve of the blade etc....

Any info would help!!!

Thanks

Comment: This is more of a web development question than a design problem. You will get better answers and resources on StackOverflow. There is a also a StackExhcnage site for UI/UX. This would fall under the UX category too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new here but I'll try answering your question based on my experiences in the web design field.

First of all, in the current web design trend, we don't actually use flash anymore since it's not widely supported by mobile gadgets. We normally use html, css & jquery scripts or even a CMS(content management system like wordpress or magento) to built the whole website.

Normally functions like this would be best found in an eCommerce website, which users shop & buy product from it. It's basically done by showing different pictures when the user clicks on the option, like a slider given with a few options on the navigation button. http://demo.yithemes.com/sistina/all-products/pullover/

However, options that could be alter are basically the images that you could show. In your case if your hockey has the curve of blade options, you should need images for each of them too.

If you're thinking of building a website to sell products, I would suggest you to either purchase an eCommerce template from themeforest or get a wordpress developer for building the website.

I hope this helps. :)